# Display current running application in android programatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a android program that on of the goal is to display the current running application being used. I also have a `BroadcastReceiver` and a `Service` running in my app.

However my problem is that this code always displays my project package name and NOT the current running application.

Code:

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> RAP= mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo: RAP ){
        Log.e("Process name ", "" + processInfo.processName);
    }
```

I'm running Marshmallow OS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AccessibilityService to determine which app is currently running.

The user will need to turn on your accessibility service in their settings in order for it to work and you will need to recieve windowStateChanged events by delcaring `android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged"` in your accessibility service declaration XML.

You can read more about AccessibilityServices here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html